# Datatables - How do I create a listener for when scroll is near the bottom of the table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am currently using datatablesJS(from https://datatables.net/) to show an array of results from a DB that is paginated. So on initial load the user gets index 0 and 100 rows.

I'm trying to write a function so that when the user scrolls close to the bottom of the table, it'll query for more of the table and append the results to the current data array. I have the query setup, but I don't know of a jquery or datatablesJS function that listens for how far the scroll is to the bottom of its max scroll length. Any suggestions?

Note: This question seems similar to [On dataTable scroll data should load from server side and append to existing records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410425/on-datatable-scroll-data-should-load-from-server-side-and-append-to-existing-rec), but the difference is that I only want to query when the user scrolls to the bottom. This post and from what I see on DataTables doc is that they run a Timeout till they get all the data with the ajax param for Datatables.

Comment: By datatablesJs, do you mean: https://datatables.net/ ?

Comment: yes that is what I meant sorry I will correct in post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On dataTable scroll data should load from server side and append to existing records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410425/on-datatable-scroll-data-should-load-from-server-side-and-append-to-existing-rec)

Comment: So I guess there's a difference in that I only want to query for more data when the user scrolls to the bottom. It looks like how most people do it on the documentation and in that post is they have a timeout keep pinging the service for data and append it each time till it gets all the data. Where as mine I only want to GET when the user scrolls to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a function to detect when the user has scrolled to the bottom of the table and another to fetch the next row of data.

This demo should give you some hints as to how to do that.

```js
$(function() {

  var $mytable = $("#myTable");
  var count = 3; //initial number of rows 
  var max = 50; //max number of rows (just for demo)
  var $datatable = $mytable.DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "bFilter": false
  }); //init the datatable and return a refence to it



  //listen for scroll and resize and custom 'fetchmore' events
  $(window).bind('scroll resize fetchmore', function() {
    var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var bottomOfTable = $mytable.offset().top + $mytable.outerHeight();

    //console.log(viewportHeight, scrolltop, bottomOfTable);

    if ($(window).scrollTop() + viewportHeight >= bottomOfTable) {
      if (count < max) {
        //console.log("Fetch more data!");
        load_more();
        $(window).trigger("fetchmore"); //keep triggering this event until we've filled the viewport
      }
    }



  });

  function load_more() {
    //fetch more data here
    count++;
    $datatable.row.add([
      count + '.1',
      count + '.2 (loaded@' + Date.now() + ')'
    ]).draw(false);
  }

  //trigger initial fetch
  $(window).trigger("fetchmore");
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <table id="myTable" class="display">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1.1</td>
        <td>1.2 (initial row)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2.1</td>
        <td>2.2 (initial row)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3.1</td>
        <td>3.2 (initial row)</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```